# What would be the consequences of mixed/blended food only?

Tags: food

Let's say you have been eating only mixed/blended food (but the food itself can be rich in nutriments) since birth during 15 years, what would be the consequences on the human body (and possibly on the mind) ?

Comment: As in, you only eat smoothies for life? Should be fine.

Comment: The chance of death by choking will decline dramatically.

Comment: I remember reading something about the importance of chewing and the brain, though I don't really know in detail. I found an article https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4466515/ which might give some insight.

Comment: @awelotta freeze the smoothie and it becomes chewable.

Comment: And no chewing gum, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only possible difference would be weak chewing muscles.

**if** the kid has bad posture.

Good dental posture alone and good breathing is enough to develop strong chewing muscles.

It is known in the medical field that kids growing up as mouth breathers develop jaw and neck deformities.

You know the Hollywood squared jawline? That's just normal anatomy of Caucasians and dravinian humans. Having weak muscles deforms the face. Blacks and Asians have different jawlines but they can also developed deformities from weak muscles.

The kid might actually be healthier overall if good oral posture is used. Because chewing things excessively hard for prolonged periods can result in a masseter being too strong and causing tinnitus and deforming teeth.

And blended food is easier to digest, which requires less bacterial breakdown.

Gut bacteria might be seen as healthy, but a good chunk of the species living inside us are deadly and increase our overall mortality rate by giving us cancers in the bum (first* most common cancer type in males)... Google Trimethylamine N-oxide and colo-rectal cancer.

The faster you digest the food, the less time it spends in your gut feeding those bacteria, and the type of food matters too.